# Shibboleth - is there a way to configure Access Control as either/or logic?

Tags: shibboleth

I have a Shibboleth implementation where, in my shibboleth2.xml file, my Host section has an AccessControl Rule that requires a isMemberOf for a group and this works great.

If I add another rule for a different group, it seems to require that the user be a member of both groups.

In my use case, I want people from Group A as well as people from Group B to have access but I don't want anyone else to have access. Is there a way that I can configure AccessControl rules so that it doesn't require both groups but requires either Group A or Group B?

Answer (score 0):

It took me forever to find this but it is well-documented in the Shibboleth wiki. The issue I ran into was that I was only looking at the AccessControl documentation but needed to look at the linked XML Access Control documentation which provides more details on usage:
https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SP3/XMLAccessControl

There are OR and AND tags that I can utilize to accomplish what I need.